# Split a MYSQL string into an ( array, like, expression, list) that IN () can understand

Tags: mysql, arrays, string, split

I have created two tables:

```
A (A.id,A.name) 
B (B.A_ids)
```

`B.A_ids` is fields of table `A.id` that are concatenated with `,`.

Now I want to query the `name` where `A.id` is in `B.A_ids`, just like this:

```
select A.name from A where A.id in(1,2,3) ;
```

However, `1,2,3` is a query from `B.A_ids`.

Comment: You can do it in oracle with the XMLTable function maybe there is something similar in MYSQL. But what I would really recommend you is redesigning your schema. For an N:M relation we usually use 3 tables and then there is no problem with the query and it will be a lot faster.

Comment: See normalisation. You should not have a comma separated list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
 SELECT A.* FROM A JOIN B
 WHERE (
   B.a_ids LIKE CONCAT(a.id,',%') 
   OR B.a_ids LIKE CONCAT('%,',a.id,',%')
   OR B.a_ids LIKE CONCAT('%,',a.id)
   OR B.a_ids = a.id 
 )
 AND B.... = ...
```

The performance can be bad. For a more efficient design, you should store the one-to-many or many-to-many relationship in another table.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a way myself using `find_in_set`:

```
select distinct(b.id),
       a.id,
       a.name,
       b.a_ids
from   A
where  find_in_set(a.id,b.a_ids);
```

Comment: Xiao, distinct is not a function, and this is a poor solution (although FIND_IN_SET is, admittedly, blisteringly fast)